# Plot the peaks of a histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to figure out how to plot the peaks of a simple histogram using `scipy.signal.find_peaks` but the peaks found seem way off.

```
ages = np.array([10, 5, 22, 13, 50, 45, 67, 30, 21, 34, 60, 67, 89, 45, 45, 65])
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(ages, 10)
bin_edges = bin_edges[1:]

plt.plot(bin_edges, hist)
peaks, _ = find_peaks(hist)
plt.plot(ages[peaks], peaks, "x")
```

[image: plotted peaks]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try:

```
plt.plot(bin_edges[peaks], hist[peaks], "x")
```

`find_peaks` gives you the indices of local maxima in the `hist` signal.

The `x-values` of your histogram are `bin_edges` and the `y-values` are given by `hist`. So you have to look for the indices given by `peaks` in each of these series.

Comment: Wow that looks great! Thank you! That looks like the right answer to me. Can you add an explanation as to what this line is doing? How is it relating the peaks to the x and y since peaks is a 1d array?

Comment: I updated the answer with a bit more explanation :)

Comment: It is worth noting that histograms are not always the best way to visualise a distribution, and can lead to misleading interpretations of the data: a simple change of bin width can drastically change their form.  Depending on your application, a better(?) way may be to calculate the "kernel density estimation" (see https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/) though, of course, in this example it might be overkill!