# Peaks Find on Hist and DF Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We are trying to wrote a code that help us to find peaks in a histo like this:

[image]

In the previus image we can see 13 peaks that we want to find and put in a pandas DF. In order to do this we wrote the following:

```
fig1 = px.histogram(df[(df['CH']==44)], x='HG', title='HG Multiphoton Spectrum')
#fig1 = px.histogram(df, x='HG', title='HG Multiphoton Spectrum')
fig1.update_traces(xbins=dict(start=0, end=8196, size=2))
fig1.show()


data = df[(df['CH']==44)]

data_raw = data[['HG']].T

data_final = np.array(data_raw).squeeze()

print(data_final)

x = data_final

peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, height=50, width=10)

counts, bins = np.histogram(data_final)
plt.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=counts)

plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "x")

plt.show()
```

But the code gives this output:

[image]

I don't understand why i don't see the previous histo with the peaks that the code find. It is possible to use pyplot for implement the hist like the previous?

Here the full [code](https://mega.nz/file/Z4wG2QIR#bS0ZXRg0qjCzw6WqgK7Te-nC4L0SEeA7M1NOCtjK1Rs) and [data file](https://mega.nz/file/NsAjlK4A#6j3QdtNe-cOcZ934KIWrYjkAtly6Jov5PH-GjLXytlU):

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you also upload a sample dataframe to test the code?

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57277536/plot-the-peaks-of-a-histogram
Looks very similar to your problem

Comment: Sure @Minh-TuanNguyen, you can find it in the post (I edited it, you can find the full code and dataset).

Comment: Thanks you @OnurGuven, but seems to not give the right results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off there is a difference between outputs of `plotly` histogram and `np.histogram` that is probably the most confusing part about this.

Here is the code that generates the output you are looking for:

```
c = [value for value in x if value < 1000]
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(c, bins=5000)

peaks, _ = find_peaks(hist, distance=500)
bin_edges = bin_edges[1:]

plt.plot(bin_edges, hist)
plt.plot(bin_edges[peaks], hist[peaks], "x")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: output_figure]

The reason for filtering input x is to simulate that range you give to your initial histogram plot (`start=0, end=8196`), I could not make it work with `range` variable for `np.histogram` so you can modify this `1000` value by your choice based on looking at your initial histogram. And `bins` variable in `np.histogram` is basically `your_input / your_bin_size`

Comment: Thanks for you reply, it was very usefull for us!!! 

Oh yes, we are trying to use plotly only because it can be plot simultaneously more than one plot. 

In your opinion, it is possible to do the same job with it?

Comment: Glad it helped. If you are referring to plotting the same plots with `plotly`, yeah I bet you can do it you already have the values for histogram + peaks. Try something like this(I don't know how to put them in the same figure, haven't used `plotly`):
```px.bar(x=bin_edges, y=hist)
px.scatter(x=bin_edges[peaks], y=hist[peaks])```